# Replacing top references in a frameset based web application

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to put a pega workflow web application in an Iframe.
This application was previously launched as an independent browser window & has multiple references to top object within JavaScript & uses frameset.

Unfortunately i don't have the liberty to change application code, so i am using apache as a reverse proxy & mod_substitute to replace the references of top which is working.

However when i replace top with window/parent/self the application seems to be broken with JavaScript errors.

Wondering if anybody faced this situation before, I couldn't find a convincing/working answer for this anywhere.

Comment: Does your iframe display page from the same domain or corresponding subdomain or not?

Comment: If you had included the element that defines the iframe, and the javascript that gave you the error, you would have had a better chance of getting your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

give the iframe a name attribute and you can then replace all of the top references with that name

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_name.asp)